# Convert a string that contains json to pure json

Tags: c#, json

I have a data model in MVC like:

```
public class Column
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
    public string C3 { get; set; }
}
```

Each property has to be strings!

It can have values like:

```
var column = new Column { 
    C1 = "Some text",
    C2 = "22",
    C3 ="{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"a name\"}"
};
```

I serialize data to json with newtonsoft:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(column);
```

And I get:

> "{\"C1\":\"Some
>   text\",\"C2\":\"22\",\"C3\":\"{\\"id\\":12,\\"name\\":\\"a
>   name\\"}\"}"

But I would like C3 to get serialized as an object:

> "{\"C1\":\"Some text\",\"C2\":\"22\",\"C3\":{\"Id\":22,\"Name\":\"a
>   name\"}}"

How can I do that? I know explitly that it's C3 that contains a text that should be serialized.

Comment: Do all the properties really have to be strings? E.g. could `C3` be an `IDictionary<string, object>` instead? If it cannot, then you could parse the JSON strings first, but you would have to know which properties are JSON strings in the first place (possibly through an attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
public static string SerializeObject(
    Object value,
    params JsonConverter[] converters
)
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_4.htm

Then, you can pass your own converter which can handle the desired usecase for you, which might look like this.

```
 public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.Equals(typeof(String));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //no need, we are setting canRed to false. 
            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (((String)value).StartsWith("{")){ //more accuracy required here ofc. 
                //Take that as a json String
                writer.WriteRawValue((String)value);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

(the only thing this does, is: if the value starts with `{`, we use `writeRawValue` rather than `writeValue`. Condition needs improvement ofc.)

finally, use:

```
 JsonConverter[] converters = new JsonConverter[1];
 converters[0] = new MyJsonConverter();
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(column, converters);
```

to convert using your special converter for string types.

Comment: Thank you so much Dognose – thats exactly what I needed. Awesome.

Comment: @KennethBoChristensen You're welcome. I'm not familiar with `writer.writeValue()` - maybe you need to find a way to call the default implementation for processing strings in order to perform proper escaping. But you should be able to figure this out with a few tests.

Comment: I ended up with this solution. Please let me know if I should make changes to it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ls5ZRk

Comment: Its code not pure and used package newtonsoft JSON.NET

Answer (score 1):

Since your c3 is a different type essentially, you could separate it out.

JSON.Net library wouldnt be able to serialize an already serialized string. It would first need to be parsed out or "Deserialized" before feeding it back to the Serializer.

But incase you are generating C3 using another method, I would suggest you de-couple that so that JSON.Net serializer would understand the type that needs to serialize and give you a proper formatted JSON string.

```
public class Column
    {
        public string C1 { get; set; }
        public string C2 { get; set; }
        public Column2 C3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


var col2 = new Column2 { Id = 12, Name = "John Doe" };

            var column = new Column
            {
                C1 = "Some text",
                C2 = "22",
                C3 = col2
            };
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(column));
```

[.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CRoT8K)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but C3, has to be a string. A plus for .Net fiddler – didn’t know that page - perfect for an example like this.